# Swaping background in div - jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I have the following structure of html

```
<div id="cool" class="cool"></div>
<div id="cool2" class="cool2"></div>
<button id="button">Click Me</button>
```

On the click of button, how would i `swap` the `color`. The div's are not childrens of any.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $("#button").on('click', function(){
       $("#cool").addClass("cool2").removeClass("cool"); 
       $("#cool2").addClass("cool").removeClass("cool2");           
  });  
});
```

I know there is something `toggleClass()`, but how would you swap the backgrounds of two div containers who are not childrens or should i attach the even to `document` and `propagate` to button to get the childrens?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like you posted, you may use [`toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)

> This method takes one or more class names as its parameter. In the
>   first version, if an element in the matched set of elements already
>   has the class, then it is removed; if an element does not have the
>   class, then it is added.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $("#button").on('click', function(){
       $("#cool, #cool2").toggleClass("cool cool2");          
  });  
});
```

```css
div
{
    height: 50px;
}

.cool
{
    background-color: gray; 
}
.cool2
{
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cool" class="cool"></div>
<div id="cool2" class="cool2"></div>
<button id="button">Click Me</button>
```